# PHP serialization with non-serializable parts

Tags: php, serialization

I have a PHP class that stores database query results, but also contains a PDO object so that the results can be updated/re-inserted/etc on the fly.  A makeshift ORM, if you will.

Problem is, I need to serialize this class but instances of PDO cannot be serialized.  I'm ok with that; by the time the object gets serialized, I have no need for the PDO instance.

Is there a way to mark a variable for exclusion from serialization within a class, like there are with some other languages?  I understand I could manually unset() the PDO variable before I want to serialize the class, but with the current structure of the code, that would be a bit of a nightmare.

My saving grace here would be a __serialize() method that could be overridden, but it doesn't appear anything like that exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Transient" properties in a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114368/transient-properties-in-a-php-class)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's [__sleep() and __wakeup()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep).

Alternatively, you could implement [Serializable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.serializable.php).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks, Ionut G. Stan!

Answer (score 0):

Starting with PHP 7.4, there is also `__serialize` and `__unserialize` (see the [Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.serialize)) as a more usable alternative.

The `Serializable` interface might also be [deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/phase_out_serializable), and generally the magic methods are preferred (see also [this](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/custom_object_serialization#serializable)).