# how to hide properties of class during serialization?

Tags: php, serialization, getter-setter

can i override function that is responsbile for serializing and Php class to an array/stdclass so that i can implement my own logic "like hiding certain attributes based on condition)

```
class UserModel{
  $hidden = ['password'];

  function __construct(array $data) {
    foreach($data as $key=>$value)$this->$key = $value;
  }

}

$user = new UserModel(['id'=>1,'password'=>123]);

var_dump($user);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Transient" properties in a PHP class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114368/transient-properties-in-a-php-class)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about implementing the [Serializable interface](http://php.net/manual/de/class.serializable.php)?
Looks like you can do your custom logic by implementing the interface methods.

Example:

```
class UserModel implements Serializable {

    // returns string
    public function serialize() {
        $data = array(
            'id' => $this->id,
            'password' => null, // or omit password
            'email' => $this->email,
            ...
        );
        return serialize($data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Cheers ! thatns did not the interface name, thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite a method

Just look at the small exemple of the classe below;

```
 class User { 
 //To hide
 private $pass;

 //To show
 private $log;
 private $nbPoints;

  {...}
  public function serialize()
  {
    $arr = [];
    $arr['LOG'] = $this->log;
    $arr['POINTS'] = $this->nbPoints;
    return ($arr);
  }
}
```

You can var_dump the return of the `User->serialize` method and password will ne be showed.

If you need all your class, then crypt or hash all variable you need to hide.

Here is two famous (but unsafe) method in cryptology : `MD5` `Ceaser cipher`

Just understand well the difference between hashing and crypting datas

(HASH : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5);

(CRYPTING : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher);

Comment: problem is i dont control how and when this class might be serialized, so i want to override php default serialization method

Comment: I did not recommend you to do that, instead use a crypting or a hashing method for hiding specific datas

Answer (score 0):

For a simple solution you can also use __sleep Magic Method.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

```
class UserModel {
    protected $id;
    protected $password;
    protected $username;
    protected $email;

    public function __sleep(){
       return array('id','username','email');
    }
}
```